# Issue setting ylim using geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I run the following code for a bar-plot using ggplot. I need the y-axis to be between 0 and 1. I used functions as ....+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,1)) and +continuous_scale,  but it didn't work out.

```
mu.alpha<-c(0.923, 
            0.911, 
            0.873, 
            0.889, 
            0.932, 
            0.939) 

V2<-c(10,25,50,10,25,50)
V3<-c("N-N","N-N","N-N","S-S","S-S","S-S")         

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(mu.alpha, V2,V3))
x2 <-ggplot(data=data, aes(x=V2, y=mu.alpha, fill=V3)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge()) + theme_minimal()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues") + theme(legend.position = "none")
x2
```

Comment: Don't use `cbind()` in side `data.frame()`. It messes with your data types by first coercing to a matrix. It's a bad practice that a lot of people do for some reason. Just use `data <- data.frame(mu.alpha, V2,V3)` and then you can use `x2+ylim(0,1)` as you expect becuase it won't be converted to a factor.

Comment: Look at `str(data)`. By creating a data frame like this after `cbind`, you've made all the columns into factors. You probably want your y variable to be numeric

Comment: @MrFlick thanks a lot for the suggestion about cbind :) , however I got the following error using '''x2+ylim(0,1)''' : "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: Then your data is still a factor for some reason. You originally had different variable names in your code. Are you passing the right data.frame when you test the code? Because I cannot reproduce when I swap out the line I suggested.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions, problem solved!